# Integrating AWS API Gateway with Cloud Front without exposing origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a project with serverless architecture.

I've found that though AWS said API Gateway can protect your resources from DDoS attack.

But if there is a bad user which keep sending spam to your service,

API gateway can't provide an appropriate way to handle this kind of issues.

So I start to figure out what I can do:

- AWS WAF is an obviously solution.

I've found this post on stackoverflow: [API gateway with aws waf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421357/aws-api-gateway-with-aws-waf)

Then in order to setup WAF,

I put a Cloud Front distribution in front of the API Gateway.

I realized this might be a workaround solution, but is it?

Here's the issue I found:

1. I have a cloud front distribution, its domain name is `cdn.net`
2. I set the origin path to my api gateway: `https://sampleagigw.amazon.com`, and set path to its stage `dev`.
3. When I call GET `http://cdn.net/posts`, it will return a result which I expect.
4. Then if you put the `http://cdn.net/posts` on browser, it surprised you more than your expect, it also expose the API gateway's url on the url bar of browser: `https://sampleagigw.amazon.com/dev/posts`

It means all of the work with WAF and Cloud front is meaningless.

Is there anything I misunderstood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the "Viewer Protocol Policy" on your additional CloudFront distribution (cdn.net) and ensure that it is set to either "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" or "HTTPS Only".  Alterntively, you can edit your origin and set "Origin Protocol Policy" to "HTTPS Only".

If you have "Viewer Protocol Policy" set to "HTTP and HTTPS" and "Origin Protocol Policy" set to "Match Viewer", then I can see how you would get this result.  You enter `http://cdn.net/posts` on browser, then the cdn.net distribution attempts to connect to `http://sampleagigw.amazon.com` (no https/tls/ssl).  This goes to the CloudFront distribution created by API Gateway which is set to "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS".  Since it got an HTTP request, it returns a 302 redirect to `http://sampleagigw.amazon.com`.  This is returned by the cdn.net distribution to the browser.  The browser then follows the 302 redirect, leaving the `http://sampleagigw.amazon.com` URL in the browser's URL bar.

Comment: That's it!! I forgot to set the Origin Protocol Policy, thanks a lot!