# Adding Lambda@edge includebody field in cloudfront using cloudformation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to add `Lambda@Edge` association in cloudfront using cloudformation. As per [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-lambdafunctionassociation.html) they had only two fields like `EventType` and `LambdaFunctionARN` . But i want to add `IncludeBody` in cloudformation so that my `Lambda@Edge` will read the body of the request . When i try to add  `IncludeBody` in cloudformation it is saying error like `invalid property`.

```
"LambdaFunctionAssociations":
[
            {
                "EventType": "origin-response",
                "IncludeBody":"true" -- Invalid property error 
                "LambdaFunctionARN": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:134952096518:function:LambdaEdge:1"
            }
]
```

So, can't i add this through cloudformation . Or i need to do it manually from console ?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_LambdaFunctionAssociation.html), there is an `IncludeBody` property for `LambdaFunctionAssociation`s.  But [they also say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-include-body-access.html) that it can only be used for "viewer-request" and "origin-request" `EventType`s.  It looks like you have an "origin-response" `EventType`, so `IncludeBody` shouldn't be applicable here.  Yet, in the [official CloudFormation reference](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-lambdafunctionassociation.md), there is no mention of `IncludeBody`.  So I can only guess that CloudFormation is missing this feature right now and you may only be able to set `IncludeBody` via the API.